# Trouble With WHERE clause when creating temporary Column

Tags: sql, mariadb

I've written a query that creates a new temporary row with the frequency an id is shown, and I need to remove any items that are below my filter requirement of frequency, which is 4. The code works as planned, until I add the where clause (below). What is the reason that you cannot add a where clause where you normally would?

```
  SELECT RecipeTitle, COUNT(recipes.RecipeID) AS ingredientsNeeded FROM recipes 
         INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ON recipe_ingredients.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
              GROUP BY recipes.RecipeID 
              ORDER BY ingredientsNeeded ASC
```

Returns

```
Calzone | 3 
Hot dog | 2
```

etc

```
SELECT RecipeTitle, COUNT(recipes.RecipeID) AS ingredientsNeeded FROM recipes 
     INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ON recipe_ingredients.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
          GROUP BY recipes.RecipeID 
          WHERE ingredientsNeeded < 4
          ORDER BY ingredientsNeeded ASC
```

You get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL Syntax... check manual for right syntax to use near WHERE...

Comment: I don't see an issue with your query, unless either your `INNER JOIN` finds no matches or there are no rows that satisfy the `WHERE` condition. *The code works as planned unless* is not really a clear problem description. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. For future reference, when you get an error, you should always  include the specific error message in your post. You're asking us for free help to solve your problem, so it's in your best interest to provide us with all of the relevant information you have to make it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `HAVING` clause to make assertions on the count:

```
SELECT
    r.RecipeTitle,                          -- potentially OK to select this, see below
    COUNT(r.RecipeID) AS ingredientsNeeded
FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ri
    ON ri.RecipeID = r.RecipeID
GROUP BY
    r.RecipeID 
HAVING
    ingredientsNeeded < 4
ORDER BY
    ingredientsNeeded;
```

Note that you are aggregating by the `RecipeID`, so technically you are only allowed to select that, *or* any aggregate.  However, selecting `RecipeTitle` is allowed if `RecipeID` is the primary key of the `recipes` table.